# Triggers or Procedures

Tags: mysql, cakephp, optimization

I am currently working on a web application using CakePhp as a framework and MySql as a RDMBS. The application will be used later on by tens (probably hundreds) of users at the same time and they might actually be updating the database several times a day, and I want to keep track of all the changes to the database for later analysis. Now, and **in terms of optimizing my script/application**, do you think that it would be better to use classic Triggers or Stored Procedures ,in order to keep track of any changes to the database after each "insert","update" or "delete" action done by the user.

Comment: Triggers have the advantage of "working" no matter what the front end/ application layer is (e.g., Cakephp, php, sql code, etc.) and the advantage of using Cakephp 'as is'. Getting Cakephp to use stored proc's is going to require more work than the triggers solution.

Comment: If I've understood correctly, you want the RDBMS to maintain an audit trail? This isn't something that a stored procedure run after the event can accomplish—e.g. consider multiple changes occurring between invocations, or how the user responsible for a detected change would be identified? Perhaps by "stored procedure" you meant that users would be forced to use your sprocs to perform write operations? If so, then there would be little difference "*in terms of optimizing your script/application*" versus using triggers: the biggest tradeoffs would likely be between security and maintainability.

Comment: That said, is it really necessary to build this using database-stored code anyway: MySQL's [general query log](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/query-log.html) records this information already, so perhaps that is sufficient for your needs?  However, I'd personally performing user-based audit logging at the application-level (since it will have a fuller context for recording relevant information—indeed, applications typically use the same database credentials irrespective of real-world user, and it's the actions of the latter that one wishes to audit).

Comment: Why not just use something like the [CakePHP Audit Log Plugin](https://github.com/robwilkerson/CakePHP-Audit-Log-Plugin)? I've been successfully using it in a few 2.x projects.